# COMO RODAR UMA APLICAÇÃO COM DOCKER

Tags: docker

Eai meu consagrados!!

Criei dois containers rodando linux e estou tentando fazer a comunicação entre dois containers. Quero trocar mensagens entre esses containers através de aplicações Python e Java. Uma dessas linguagens para implementar o cliente e a outra para o servidor.

Como eu faço para rodar uma aplicação nesses containers?

Como eu faço a comunicação utilizando uma aplicação.

Obs: A aplicação que estou usando é um simples código que pede um numero e digito.

Answer (score 0):

> Como eu faço para rodar uma aplicação nesses containers?

De forma grosseira você deve entrar dentro do container e instalar o programa, ajuda se tiver criado um volume ou um ponto de compartilhamento na hora da criação dos containers. Você pode acessar os container com o comando:

```
docker exec -ti nome-do-container /bin/bash
```

Isso lhe dará acesso ao terminal do container. Aí é só instalar o programa.

[Documentação docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)

Obs: Essa forma não é a mais indicada para rodar um programa dentro de um container, o ideal seria usar um entrypoint.

[Boas práticas no docker](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)

> Como eu faço a comunicação utilizando uma aplicação.

Você deve expor a porta do container servidor no momento da sua criação com a opção --publish ou -p, assim ela fica acessível para o outro container.

[Documentação docker run](https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/edge/engine/reference/commandline/run/#capture-container-id-cidfile)

Comment: Eu poderia entrar em contato com você para uma maior ajuda? Claro, se você estiver com tempo disponível.